# Concerned about the size of my Aggregate Root

Tags: performance, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I am new to DDD and have a concern about the size of my Aggregate Root. The object graph is like the image below. (They are collections). The problem is all of the entities depend on the state of the AggregateRoot (Event). My question is: how do I break the aggregate into smaller aggregates? It's like I have a "God" like aggregate root that just manages everything.

This is very simplistic view of my domain:

[image]

and these are the rules:

- An event has a number of different states. (implemented state design
  pattern here).
- An event has a collection of sessions. (but only 1 can be active at a time and only if the event is in the correct state).
- A session has two states: Active and Ended.
- A session has a collection of Guests.
- A session has a collection of photos. (Maximum
  of 10).
- When a session is deleted. It should delete all its children.
- When a session has ended and a photo is deleted it should
  check to see if there are any other photos that belong to the
  session. If not it should also delete the session.
- When a session has ended and a photo is deleted sometimes it should throw an exception depending on the state of the event.
- When a session is active and a photo is deleted. It should not worry about whether or not the session has any other photos or not.
- When a session ends it must have at least 1 photo and at least 1 guest.
- A photo can be updated but only if the event is in the right state.
- When an event is deleted it should delete all its children.

Edit: I have divided the 1 aggregate into smaller aggregates so that Event, Session and Photo are all ARs. The issues is a session needs to perform a check on the Event AR before starting. Is it perfectly ok to inject an event object into the sessions start method Session.Start(Event @event) or will I have concurrency issues as outlined in some of the comments?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, the following 3 articles will be invaluable: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

With DDD you are splitting the entities up in to boundaries where the state is valid after a single operation from an external source completes (i.e. a method call).

Think in terms of the business problem you are trying to solve - you have used the word delete a lot...

Does delete even have a place in the wording of the business experts for whom you are designing the system? Thinking in terms of the real world and not database infrastructure, unless you can create a time machine to travel back in time and stop an event from starting and therefore change history, the word delete has no real world analogy.

If you are forcing yourself to delete children on delete, that means that operation would need to become a transaction so things that may not make sense to sit inside the aggregate root are forced too (so that the state of the entity and all its children can be controlled and assured to be valid once the method call completes). Yes there are things where you can do with a transaction across multiple aggregate roots, but these are very rare situations and to be avoided if possible.

Eventual consistency is used as an alternative to transactions and reduce complexity, if you speak to the person for whom the system is being designed, you will probably find that a delay of seconds or minutes is more than acceptable. This is plenty of time to fire off an event, to which some other business logic is listening and takes necessary action. Using eventual consistency removes the headaches that come with transactions.

Photos could take up a lot of storage yes, so you would probably need a cleanup mechanism that runs after an event is marked as finished. I would probably fire off an event once the session is marked closed, a different system somewhere else would listen for this event and after 1 year (or whatever makes sense for you) remove this from a server... assuming you used an array of string[10] for your URLs.

If this is the maximum extent of your business logic, then don't only focus on DDD, it seems like this could be a good fit for Entity Framework which is essentially CRUD and has cascade deletes built in.

**Edits answer**

What is a photo, does it contain attributes? Is it not instead something like a Url to a photo, or a path to a picture file?

I'm not yet thinking of databases, that should be the very last thing that is thought of and the solution should be database/technology agnostic. I see the rules as:

- An event has many sessions.
- A Session has the following states: NotStarted, Started and Ended.
- A Session has a collection of Guests, I'm going to assume these are unique (in that two guests with the same name are not the same, so a guest should be an aggregate root).
- An Event has one active Session.
- When there are no active Sessions, an Event can be marked as Finished.
- No Sessions can be started once an Event is marked as Finished.
- A session has a collection of up to 10 photos.
- When a session has ended, a photo cannot be removed.
- A Session can not start if there are no Guests A Session can not end if there are no Photos.

You cannot return the Session directly, as a user of your code may call Start() on the session, you will need someway of checking with the Event that this cannot be started, so you can chain up to the root this is why I pass in the event to the Session. If you don't like this way, then just put the methods that manipulate the Session on the Event (so everything is accessed via the Event, which is enforcing all the rules).

In the simplest case, I see the photo as a string (value object) in the Session entity. As a first stab I would do something like this:

```
// untested, do not know if will compile!
public class Event
{
    List<Session> sessions = new List<Session>();

    bool isEventClosed = false;

    EventId NewSession(string description, string speaker)
    {
        if(isEventClosed==true) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot add session to closed event");

        // create a new session, what will you use for identity, string, guid etc
        var sessionId = new SessionId(); // in this case autogenerate a guid inside this class

        this.sessions.Add(new Session(sessionId, description, speaker));
    }

    Session GetSession(EventId id)
    {
        reutrn this.sessions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
    }   

    bool CanStartSession(Session session)
    {
        // TO DO: do a check session is in our array!!
        if(this.isEventClosed == true)
            return false;

        foreach(var session in sessions)
        {
            if(session.IsStarted()==true)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class Session
{
    List<GuestId> guests = new List<GuestId>(); // list of guests
    List<string> photoUrls = new List<string>(); // strings to photo urls
    readonly SessionId id;
    DateTime started = null;
    DateTime ended = null;
    readonly Event parentEvent;

    public Session(Event parent, SessionId id, string description, string speaker)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentEvent = parent;
        // store all the other params
    }

    void AddGuest(GuestId guestId)
    {
        this.guests.Add(guestId);
    }

    void RemoveGuest(GuestId guestId)
    {
        if(this.IsEnded())
             throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot remove guest after event has ended");
    }

    void AddPhoto(string url)
    {
        if(this.photos.Count>10)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cannot add more than 10 photos");

        this.photos.Add(url);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if(this.guests.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cant start session without guests");

        if(CanBeStarted())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("already started");

        if(this.parentEvent.CanStartSession()==false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("another session at our event is already underway or the event is closed");

        this.started = DateTime.UtcNow;     
    }

    void End()
    {
        if(IsEnded()==true)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("session already ended");

        if(this.photos.length==0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cant end session without photos");

        this.ended = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // can raise event here that session has ended, see mediator/event-hander pattern
    }

    bool CanBeStarted()
    {
        return (IsStarted()==false && IsEnded()==false);
    }

    bool IsStarted()
    {
        return this.started!=null;
    }

    bool IsEnded()
    {
        return this.ended!=null;
    }   
}
```

No warranty on the above, and may well need to change over time as the understanding evolves and as you see better ways to re-factor the code.

**A guest cannot be removed once a session has ended** - this logic has been added with a simple test.

**Talk about deletion of guests and leaving sessions with 0 guests** - you have stated that guests cannot be removed once an event has ended... by allowing that to happen at any point would be in violation of that business rule, so it can't ever happen, ever. Besides, using the term to delete a person in your problem space makes no sense as people cannot be deleted, they existed and will always have a record that they existed. This database term delete belongs in the database, not in this domain model as you have described it.

**Is `this.parentEvent.CanStartSession()==false` safe?** No it is not multithread safe, but commands would be ran independently, perhaps in parallel, each in their own thread:

```
void HandleStartSessionCommand(EventId eventId, SessionId sessionId)
{
    // repositories etc, have been provided in constructor
    var event = repository.GetById(eventId);
    var session = event.GetSession(sessionId);
    session.Start();
    repository.Save(session);
}
```

If we were using event sourcing then inside the repository it is writing the stream of changed events in a transaction, and the aggregate root's current version is used so we can detect any changes. So in terms of event sourcing, a change to the Session would indeed be a change to its parent aggregate root, since it doesn't make sense to refer to a Session event in its own right (it will always be a Event event, it cannot exist independently). Obviously the code I have given in my example is not event sourced but could be written as so.

If event sourcing is not used then depending on the transaction implementation, you could wrap the command handler in a transaction as a cross cutting concern:

```
public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler;

    public TransactionalCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decoratedHandler)
    {
        this.decoratedHandler = decoratedHandler;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            this.decoratedHandler.Handle(command);
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

In short, we are using the infrastructure implementation to provide concurrency safety.

Comment: Lets say that I was to make Photo it's own aggregate root. What I could do is when an event is deleted to fire a domain event that will eventually remove the photo. I don't have a problem with the delay that is fine... but this raises two other questions? What happens if something fails in the event to delete the photo? I will be left with stale data in the database? (it's no longer a transaction). Also I am assuming this will mean that in the database table Photo, it will have to have a null reference to the event so that when the event is deleted it can break the reference.

Comment: Also if Photo is it's own aggregate root then that means a new one can be added at any time. The only way to prevent that from happening is to inject the Event aggregate root into the photo's constructor and perform a check. I am assuming this is bad practice?

btw thank you for the response and I did have a look at that page yesterday. I understand it when I read it but I guess its more difficult to apply the concepts to your own specific problem.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using a domain service to check whether or not a photo can be created?

Comment: Have included a bit of demo code to show a couple of examples to implement the required rules

Comment: Thank you for the code. The rules seem relatively correct but keep in mind there are a number of other states for an event too. It's also missing an important rule 'A guest cannot be removed once a session has ended' Now wouldn't that mean a guest cannot be an aggregate root as it could be deleted when a session has finished, consequently leaving the session with 0 guests. In your code I am assuming Event, Session, and Photo are all part of the one aggregate with Event being the AR. If that is the case what is the purpose of raising the event in the sessions End()?

Comment: A photo contains a byte[] of the image itself and a thumbnail. I may potentially change these to file locations later on. Also one other rule that completely drives me crazy is: A photo can be removed even after an event / session have finished.

The more I think about it the more I believe that they are all part of the one aggregate. Unless I am just not seeing something!

Comment: I haven't written all of the checks, the one you mentioned should be trivial to write with the above. You really need to think about eventual consistency and ubiquitous language of the problem space... unless you a cyberdyne sending a terminator back in time you wouldn't really say the words delete or terminate people! Eventual consistency and not deleting helps. If CRUD makes more sense in this instance then go ahead and use CRUD. Hope this helps

Comment: `this.parentEvent.CanStartSession()==false` Is this really safe? What about another transaction modifying the Event state at the same time? Also, if you have a Session's collection within Event, you would have to untrack it to avoid changing a Session causing a version change on the Event, no?

Comment: @plalx Added comments to answer edit

Comment: @g18c Yes, but if changing a Session modifies the Event, then Session is not it's own aggregate root and Event is still a large cluster aggregate. The initial goal was to break them apart while protecting invariants, which perhaps is not possible and must be done embracing eventual consistency. Also, if they are in the same cluster, it means that changing the Event (e.g. it's description) would conflict with activating a session since both events would bump the root version, unless you are using event sourcing, which allows to be more granular for conflict resolution.

Comment: @plalx yes the Session is a child entity within the Event. I don't think Event with the child Sessions is too big. Concept of photos as a entity are no more, and guest are external Aggregate roots, so its significantly smaller.

Comment: @g18c Well in this case, I do not see how you try to address the OP's question. "How to break the large cluster aggregate, but protect invariants in some way" =P

Comment: He was talking about guest and photos being child entities of the aggregate root. These are no longer, guest is a external entity, and photos a string. In terms of this problem space, a Session cannot exist without an Event, so it is perfectly natural for it to live as a Child. Would you call a 2 entity aggregate huge? You can try and fight nature and reduce to single ARs but if it is good enough for now why not roll with it so you can get the first release out the door, which will allow money to come in and then pay for salaries for v2! #JustSaying! Feel free to post alternative answer :)